# How do I center my responsive form and align it evenly with everything else?

Tags: html, css, forms, internet-explorer, responsive-design

[Link to website](http://foxweb.marist.edu/users/kf79g/contact.php)

This is it. The last step I have to fix before deploying my website and finally finishing it. But I do not know how to resolve this issue. For some reason it looks as though there is a margin to the left on the contact form and the measurements are off. If you look closely at the borders I have set for testing, I want it to be exactly aligned and centered with the green border where my content is on medium and small device screens. When I shrink my page down all the way on a modern browser (firefox), the form shifts to the left and it looks like there is a margin to the right. It looks the same right now on modern browsers and IE (which is good). I would prefer any fixes to stay consistent with these older browsers. I tried changing the width of the form and tried doing what I did for my social icons and put it inside multiple containers but that did not work (unless I am doing it wrong). If anybody could help me fix this, I would really appreciate it. I will be online the rest of this weekend constantly making changes and making updates consistently so you can see your changes in effect right away.

Visual Representation of problem:

[image]

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="main_section">
                <div id = "center">

                <div id="contact_section">
                    <form method="POST" action="contact.php">
                    <span class="label">Name</span><br/>
                    <input type="text" class="textfield" name="name" size="50" maxlength="50"><br/>
                    <span class="label">Email</span><br/>
                    <input type="text" class="textfield" name="email" size="50" maxlength="50"><br/>
                    <span class="label">Subject</span><br/>
                    <input type="text" class="textfield" name="subject" size="50" maxlength="50"><br/>
                    <span class="label">Message</span><br/>
                    <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="message" id="textarea" maxlength="500"></textarea><br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" name="action"> 
                    </form>
                </div>
                </div>

        </div>
```

Main CSS:

```
#contact_section {
    max-width:100%;
    margin-bottom:40px;
    margin-right: 0px;

    margin-top:20px;
    padding: 20px 6px 20px 6px; /*Make this smaller for 100% responsiveness*/
    border-radius:10px;
    background:#f1f1f1;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 15px #272727; 
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Medium and small screen CSS:

```
#center{
width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width:100%;
border: 1px red solid;
text-align:center;
}

#contact_section {
width:95%;
max-width:100%;
 margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align:center;
  border: 1px yellow solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have `#contact_section` floated right on your main CSS so it will always align right. Try setting `float:none;` on both your divs `#details_sections` and `#contact_section` in your small screens CSS

**EDIT**

In response to your comment about your main layout, try setting your divs width in percentages:

```
#details_section {
  width: 40%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  float: left;
}

#contact_section {
  width: 55%;
  float: left;
}

#contact_section form{
  padding: 20px 6px 20px 6px;
}
```

And you would probably want to remove or adjust your inputs max-width

Comment: Okay I will change it for the details_section and contact_section give me a minute

Comment: You have to set float:none to #details_sections as well

Comment: I just did that too. When I still resize my width of my browser down even more, it still is going outside of the red border. How do I keep it in there?

Comment: Remove the padding from #contact_section and add it to the form since it adds to the width

Comment: Okay I will try this. So far your answer has been correct. I tried the other person's answer out too and unless I am doing something wrong with his answer, I will definitely keep going with your answer. If that is the case, I will comment again if I keep going with your fixes.

Comment: You sir are a genius. I will go with your answer. I was wondering if you can also help me on my large screen with the form. How do I make it bigger and still keep responsiveness? I don't like the huge white gap in between the form and the paragraphs. If not, don't worry about it.

Comment: God bless you. Thank you so much for all of your help. This would have never have gotten finished if it was not for your expertise. If there is anything you need, please let me know. I would love to repay you in some way. Thank you ever so much!

Answer (score 0):

Note that both your green frame and the contact form are not really centered.. when you use `float:right` it doesn't matter that you have `margin-right:auto;` and `margin-left:auto` cuz the float is still pushing to the right.. My suggestion is to set the width of both containers to 94% instead of 95% and add `margin-right:3%` and `margin-left:3%`..

more specifically, do this:

```
#center {
    width: 94%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
    max-width: 100%;
    border: 1px red solid;
    text-align: center;
}
```

`float:none` as koala_dev recommended can break your entire page since you've been working with floating elements so far (your container is also floated etc)..

Comment: Okay I will try this out. Give me a few minutes. I will comment again once I finish it.

Comment: Okay I tried this and this only made it smaller on the page. Am I doing something wrong?